# Combining multiple documents with Word.Application (COM interop) causes incorrect formatting?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

using .net 4.0/vs2010, office 2007

Note that I'm open to any other method to accomplish the final result.  I'm not married to Word, but I do have the restriction of not being able to include any licensed third party tool (no Aspose) and I'd like to minimize any installatio on the user's machine.  this is a corporate environment, so i do have some control.

I need to print 2 or 3 word documents as a single document.  My code follows and it works.... except that the formatting of the second document is always a little off (paragraph spacing, fonts, margins ).  Oddly enough the third document (it has a different page orientation) comes out fine.  Sometimes the user needs to send the document to a fax server, so the first page will be a fax cover sheet.

Where am I failing?? The method KillCom(object o) calls System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);

```
 public void CombineMultipleDocuments(string coverSheetPath, string[] documentPaths, string destinationFile, bool makeVisible)
        {
            List<string> docs = new List<string>();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationFile))
                throw new ArgumentException("The destinationfile is required");
            try
            {
                //strip invalid paths
                foreach (string p in documentPaths)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p) && File.Exists(p))
                    {
                        docs.Add(p);
                    }
                }

                if (docs.Count == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("There are no documents to print");
                //open the cover sheet
                wrdApp = new Word.Application();
                wrdApp.Visible = makeVisible;

                //if there is no cover sheet open the first document and append the remaining docs to it
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(coverSheetPath))
                {
                    coverSheetPath = docs[0];
                    docs.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(coverSheetPath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                wrdRange = wrdDoc.Content;

                //a little space
                wrdRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
                //attach the rest of the documents
                foreach (string path in docs)
                {
                    //open the new source document to be inserted
                    Word._Document newDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(path, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                    //continues page break
                    wrdRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                    wrdRange.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);

                    //create a new section for our new content
                    Word.Section sec = wrdRange.Sections.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                    //copy the source document's styles, fonts, etc
                    sec.PageSetup.Orientation = newDoc.PageSetup.Orientation;

                    sec.Range.Font = newDoc.Content.Font;

                    //unlink footer and headers
                    sec.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].LinkToPrevious = false;
                    sec.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.FormattedText = newDoc.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.FormattedText;

                    sec.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].LinkToPrevious = false;
                    sec.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.FormattedText = newDoc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.FormattedText;

                    wrdRange.FormattedText = newDoc.Content.FormattedText;


                    //close
                    newDoc.Saved = true;
                    newDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    newDoc = null;
                    KillCOM(newDoc);

                }

                //the diary function needs these variables to be set
                Word.Variables wrdVars = wrdDoc.Variables;

                wrdVars.Add("Letter", WrdPropLETTER_NAME);
                wrdVars.Add("FileKey", WrdPropFILE_KEY);
                wrdVars.Add("LetterTo", WrdPropLETTER_TO);
                wrdVars.Add("LetterFirstName", WrdPropLETTER_FNAME);
                wrdVars.Add("LetterLastName", WrdPropLETTER_LNAME);
                wrdVars.Add("LetterCompany", WrdPropLETTER_COMPANY);
                wrdVars.Add("LetterCategory", WrdPropLETTER_CATEGORY);
                wrdVars.Add("CurrentHeaderDoc",WrdPropCUR_HEADERDOC);
                wrdVars.Add("CurrentDataDoc", WrdPropCUR_DATADOC);


                wrdDoc.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, ref oMissing, "mojojojo");
                wrdDoc.SaveAs(destinationFile, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing
                    , ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                //close if hidden
                if (!makeVisible)
                {
                    wrdDoc.Saved = true;
                    wrdDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                    wrdApp.Quit(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    wrdDoc = null;
                    wrdApp = null;
                }

                //clean up
                if (File.Exists(coverSheetPath))
                    File.Delete(coverSheetPath);
                foreach (string path in documentPaths)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                        File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                wrdRange = null;
                wrdDoc = null;
                wrdApp = null;
                KillCOM(wrdRange);
                KillCOM(wrdDoc);
                KillCOM(wrdApp);

            }

        }
```

Comment: You're probably merging different style definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I use **PasteAndFormat** function to keep original formatting, and also copy page properties to keep margins and orientation for each document.

```
 void mergeDocumentsTest(List<string> documentFiles)
 {

        _Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        _Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
        Selection oSelection = oWord.Selection;

        foreach (string documentFile in documentFiles)
        {
            _Document oCurrentDocument = oWord.Documents.Add(documentFile);
            copyPageSetup(oCurrentDocument.PageSetup, oDoc.Sections.Last.PageSetup);
            oCurrentDocument.Range().Copy();
            oSelection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
            if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(documentFile, documentFiles.Last()))
                oSelection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
        }

        oDoc.SaveAs("testdoc.doc");
        oDoc.Close();

        //TODO: release objects, close word application

    }

    void copyPageSetup(PageSetup source, PageSetup target)
    {
        target.PaperSize = source.PaperSize;

        //target.Orientation = source.Orientation; //not working in word 2003, so here is another way
        if (!source.Orientation.Equals(target.Orientation))
            target.TogglePortrait();

        target.TopMargin = source.TopMargin;
        target.BottomMargin = source.BottomMargin;
        target.RightMargin = source.RightMargin;
        target.LeftMargin = source.LeftMargin;
        target.FooterDistance = source.FooterDistance;
        target.HeaderDistance = source.HeaderDistance;
        target.LayoutMode = source.LayoutMode;
    }
```